# how to sort string data by date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

I am working on a personal project with react and I need to show the data with chart.js.

This is the data:

[image]

I need to sort this data by date to show in line chart.

I tried to sort with this code but it's not working:

[image]

If you have any idea how to solve this please share your answer.

Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property

Comment: You need to find a way to parse these dates into `Date` objects, then you can sort them by their `.getTime()`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: Either create a daet object OR swap the parts in yyyymmdd to sort alphabetically